# select2 ajax breaks when initselection data contains &quot;

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I have a select2 ajax field where the remote data contains escaped quotes.

I use it as follows:

```
<input id="facilitiesInput" value='<%=_.pluck(facilities, "id")>' data-value='<%= JSON.stringify(facilities) %>' />
```

The problem is that one of the facilities values contains (escaped) quotes. But because I stringify the whole object and then parse it back, all quotes get interpreted as delimiters.

and the javascript code

```
$('#facilitiesInput').select2({
    ajax: {... },
    results: function (data) {
       return {results: data};
    },
},
initSelection: function (element, callback) {

  callback(JSON.parse(element.attr("data-value")));  //this is where the magic doesnt happen. parse fails because of the quotes
},
formatResult: function (facility) {
  return '<span class="facility">' + facility.name + '</span>';
},
formatSelection: function (facility) {
  return '<span class="facility">' + facility.name + '</span>';
}
});
```

the html output is

```
<input  id="facilitiesInput" value='8146' data-value='[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Facility Name&quot;,
&quot;description&quot;:&quot;&lt;p&gt;Our Motto is &quot;Carpe diem&quot;\r\n&lt;/p&gt;}]' />
```

Select2 interprets all the " as JSON delimiters, which breaks it.

Any help greatly appreciated.